# Error: In an assignment A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same

Tags: matlab

When I am running the following code, I am getting an error. The error corresponding to the specific line has been marked below.

```
global l m 
l=2;
m=4;
n=1000000;
dt=0.0001;
x=zeros(n,1);
y=zeros(n,1);
c=zeros(n,1);
t=zeros(n,1);
x(1)=1; 
y(1)=3;
c(1)=1;
t(1)=0.0;
for ii=1:1000000
    t(ii+1)=t(ii)+dt;
    x(ii+1)=x(ii)+dt*y(ii);
    y(ii+1)=y(ii)+dt*c(ii+1);
    c(ii+1)=c(ii)+dt*((1-(l/y))*c(ii) + m);
end
plot(t,x,'b');
%plot(t,y,'g');
%plot(t,c,'r');
%plot3(x,y,z);
%legend('x','y','z');
%hold on;
grid on;
%axis([0 10 0 10 0 10]);
%end
```

The corresponding error is

```
Error in ==> at 18
c(ii+1)=c(ii)+dt*((1-(l/y))*c(ii) + m);

In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and
 I must be the same.
```

Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
l/y
```

in line 18 should be

```
l/y(ii)
```

I believe.

Answer (score 0):

`y` is a vector, so you are trying to add a function of a vector with 1000,000 entries to a single entry of the `c` vector. You probably meant to add a single entry?